# VBA 2013 equivalent of IsNothing

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am currently debugging a DB application originally written in VBA 2005 that doesn't work with VBA 2010 and above versions. One of the (many) problems is that it uses the function IsNothing to test if an object variable has an object attached to it. This function seems to have been deprecated in 2010 and 2013. Is there an equivalent to this function in VBA 2013?

Answer (score 3):

As others have indicated, `IsNothing` has never been a VBA function and was likely written as syntactic sugar for `Is Nothing`.

[VB has an `IsNothing` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5adx7fxz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that serves the same purpose.  In my experience, defining VBA functions that mirror familiar VB functions is common.

Here is a [VBA `IsNothing` implementation from Tek-Tips](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=3834) that should be what you need - either to make the `IsNothing` calls work as-is...or provide a basis to inline them with equivalent code and strip the syntactic sugar:

```
'**********************************************************
'* Function: Returns true if argument evaluates to nothing
'* 1. IsNothing(Nothing) -> True
'* 2. IsNothing(NonObjectVariableOrLiteral) -> False
'* 3. IsNothing(ObjectVariable) -> True if instantiated, 
'*                                 otherwise False
'**********************************************************
Public Function IsNothing(pvarToTest As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    IsNothing = (pvarToTest Is Nothing)
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function 'IsNothing
```

In fairness, note that this is essentially what @HansUp suggested already, just sourced elsewhere - and prefaced by a best-guess how the code you're debugging likely got the way it is.

Comment: Although the topic at hand is Microsoft Access, it is worth noting that this material applies to all of the Microsoft Office applications that host VBA, including Excel, Outlook, PowerPoint, Visio, and Word, not to mention the handful of other applications that host VBA. (Corel Draw comes to mind.)

Answer (score 2):

Access VBA does not include an `IsNothing` function.  If you had one in the past, it was a custom function.

If you can't track down the old version, you could create a new one.

```vb
Public Function IsNothing(ByRef pObject As Variant) As Boolean
    IsNothing = (pObject Is Nothing)
End Function
```

Comment: I think you mean "...does not include an `IsNothing` function"?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
Dim x as Object

If x is Nothing then
```

Answer (score 0):

IsNothing itself has never been a VBA function...

```
If obj Is Nothing Then...
```

may work for you, but may not yield the same results as the IsNothing function you are expecting. You may need to code more specific checks depending on what you want to determine.